# c# get background process in windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, process, windows-services

I am build an employee monitoring application in which I have to capture all the apps used by employee I want app name ,app start time and app close time so that I save that data into sql server.

I have still capture process start time and name but I am having issuues when process or app is closed by user. like some apps including microsoft teams when closed by user my code is never hit because microsoft teams is running in background. When I end task microsoft team from task manager then my code executes. I am using C# process class. Any body who can help me in this

Answer (score 2):

By *"closed"* I assume you mean *quit*.  Some apps like Teams have an option (**On close, keep the application running**) that when right-click icon on the **Tasbbar** > **Close window** or clicking the **X** in the upper-right merely minimizes the app to the Windows *Task Tray* leaving **Teams.exe** running.  So technically the user in this case **did not** quit/close MS Teams or similar.

OP:

> When I end task microsoft team from task manager then my code executes.

That is by design.  Your code is only executed when the process exits and up until you terminated it, Teams was still running as per the user's intent.

With the **On close, keep the application running** option your code should be executed when say the user:

1. Right-clicks the Teams icon on the **Taskbar** and choses **Quit** or
2. Kills it via Task Manager or
3. Logs out of Windows

Comment: But that user is not using teams any more so If i captured that time as application usage in employee monitoring then its not correct ?

Comment: @HasnatAdil you are going to need to define _"using"_.  Is your intent for example only to track windows that are a) not minimized AND b) not hidden AND c) in-focus active?

Comment: I am monitoring employees through my software. I am saving data in db in way that employee x used microsoft teams for 2 hrs. so I am asking if user closed microsoft team and it is running in background then I should not count that time

Comment: @HasnatAdil  _"so I am asking `if user closed` microsoft `team and it is `running in background` then `I should not count that time`"_ - **incorrect**.  This is what I was alleviating to in prior comment.  Teams will appear in Task Manager (_"background"_) if **a)** background option is `disabled` and Teams icon is visible on Taskbar _OR_ **b)** background option is `enabled` and Teams may or may not be on Taskbar.  In **both** cases Teams _still shows an icon in the System Tray_.  Therefore in **both** cases `the user is still using Teams`.